# How can I mount an external hard drive in OSX safe boot mode?

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, mount, safe-mode

Is it possible to mount an external hard drive whilst in safe boot mode?  If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

So you need to use:
`mount /dev/disk1s1 /Volumes/BackupDrive`

Where `/dev/disk1s1` is the actual system device (the external drive) and /Volumes/BackupDrive is the name under which you can access it. The latter one can be anything, the /dev has to be correct though.

The actual device might be something else then disk1s1, depending on the external drive, and you might have to create the directory BackupDrive, or use something else that's available in /Volumes.

So:

`ls /dev`

to get a list of devices, your external drive should be there. I think it should be something like disk1s1, or something that looks like it.

`ls /Volumes`
there should be a directory there on which you can mount the drive. Else make one with

`mkdir /Volumes/BackupDrive`

Hope this helps.